# Bootstrap fluid container after non-fluid container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have the lower part of a webpage to be full width (in a `container-fluid` div), as opposed to the top part of the page, which is in a conventional `class="container"` div.

However, with the following html, my lower div is not full-width:

```
<div class="container">
Restricted width
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
Full-width
</div>
```

If I make the top div fluid too, both become fluid. But why can't I have a fluid container below a non-fluid container?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://www.codeply.com/go/EUKP7X7vcQ

Comment: I've just pasted that code in codepen, and it's working just as you wanted. How is it not working for you? Can you provide screenshots or some additional code?

Comment: Everything works normal here https://www.bootply.com/kV2a021RPX what is your expectation?? Can you describe the problem in clear with any working example??

Comment: Ha, the good thing about these questions is that every day I am learning about some new online editor/ code playground :). Keep 'em coming.

Answer (score 0):

Test ist

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        Restricted width
    </div>
    Full-width
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have missed closing some `<div>` in the top `container` div, otherwise, it won't affect, as per your code it would definitely work.